# Symfony installation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, symfony

I tried to install the Symfony plugin for Eclipse Indigo, but it gives an error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software being installed: Symfony Feature 1.0.94.201305191237 (`com.dubture.symfony.feature.feature.group` 1.0.94.201305191237)
>   Missing requirement: Composer Eclipse UI Plugin 1.0.2.201402150144 (`com.dubture.composer.ui` 1.0.2.201402150144) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.di 0.0.0' but it could not be found.
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Composer 1.0.2.201402150144 (`com.dubture.composer.feature.feature.group` 1.0.2.201402150144)
>   To: `com.dubture.composer.ui` [1.0.2.201402150144]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Symfony Feature 1.0.94.201305191237 (`com.dubture.symfony.feature.feature.group` 1.0.94.201305191237)
>   To: `com.dubture.composer.feature.feature.group` 1.0.2

I have to install some additional things before I can install this one. Where can I find them?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Hi Javad, eclipse indigo

Comment: I would recommend to install the new version of Eclipse which is Kepler, because the Symfony plugin has some same problem in previous versions of Eclipse

Comment: Javad, I have installed Kepler also. That gives another error "github//pulse00 ...." has not found... what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I answered your question and hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the composer plugin on the official eclipse website's marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your update to Kepler version:

1. After installing Eclipse Kepler make sure you install the *PHP Development Tools (PDT) Run Time Feature* and *PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature* (all should be version 3.1.1 or higher)
2. Next you can install the Symfony Feature by following this instruction Help>Install new software; Click *Add* in the window set Name as *Symfony Plugin* and the Location as *http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/*; By pressing OK through the listed plugins select Symfony and other needed plugins like Doctrine, ...

Hopefully this will help you